# inserting a variable into a jquery string to create a command

Tags: javascript, jquery

Stupid question no doubt but driving me mad!

Django template html but really a jquery question.

The following line checks a checkbox on my page....

```
$(id_exam_choices_1).prop('checked', true);
```

Fine no problem.

I want to create the same using a variable...

```
value = 1;
var thename = 'id_exam_choices_' + value;
alert(thename);
```

The alert shows the string is correct ....

How do I feed the variable into a command...??

```
$(thename).prop('checked', true);
```

I hope this is enough info - it seems straightforward but ....

Thanks.

Comment: Selectors for ids are expected to start with `#`.  I don't see that in your logic

Comment: What isn't working?  How is `id_exam_choices_1` defined?

Comment: `$('#' + thename)`

Comment: Cheers Adam H you are a superstar

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/  You should review and learn the basics.  It will greatly help you in your developmental process.

Comment: @Taplar is 100% correct, spend the 20 minutes reading that link and it will make your life infinitely easier in the future.

Comment: Too busy Taplar - I dont mess with this stuff often.

Comment: Yet, how much time did it take for you to post this question, and wait for an answer?  That could have been avoided by leaning the basics.

Comment: Well i guess we will see you in a couple weeks when you have another problem ;)

Comment: Not to mention, learning selectors is not related only to jQuery.  These selectors also apply to CSS.

Comment: Thanks Zuhair - the time you took to answer this humbles me and my apparent laziness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure that I got your question correctly. If you are trying to check a checkbox depending on its number which is decided by `value` variable number then I would propose this solution. i.e if `value=3` then checkbox with `id= id_exam_choices_3` will be checked and so on.

```js
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
        var value = 3;
        var thename = "id_exam_choices_" + value;
        $("body").find('#' + thename).prop("checked", true);
        });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <span name="a">Check it</span>  <input type="checkbox"  id="id_exam_choices_1"  />
        <span name="a">Check it</span>  <input type="checkbox"  id="id_exam_choices_2"  />
<span name="a">Check it</span>  <input type="checkbox"  id="id_exam_choices_3"  />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```